# How to check if a string contains only letters?

Tags: java

How to check if a string contains only letters? is there any specific functions that does that ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by letters.

Comment: @xehpuk That's reasonably defined by Unicode and POSIX character classes.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Yeah, there would be `\p{L}` but it's not clear if that's what OP meant.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a direct function But you can follow these steps :

1) Take a string as input
2) By using `toLower()` method, convert everything into lower case
3) Use `toCharArray()` method of the String class to convert into a character array
4) Now check whether at every location has character between a to z

code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringValidation{
   public boolean validtaeString(String str) {
      str = str.toLowerCase();
      char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
         char ch = charArray[i];
         if (!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a string value: ");
      String str = sc.next();
      StringValidation obj = new StringValidation();
      boolean bool = obj.validtaeString(str);
      if(!bool) {
         System.out.println("Given String is invalid");
      }else{
         System.out.println("Given String is valid");
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Output: 

Enter a string value:
24stackoverflow
Given String is invalid
------------------------
Enter a string value:
StackOverflow
Given String is valid
```

Comment: I think that with this code you don't use the Java API correctly

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Yes, it may be possible. Using regex is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to test if a string matches the pattern `/^[a-z]+$/i` if you're only concerned about simple English unaccented letters.

For letters in many languages, you can use `/^\p{L}+$/i`.

As Java regexes, these look like:

`Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

`Pattern.compile("^\\p{L}+$")`

Update: {L} works better than {Alpha} for accented characters.

```
        pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\p{L}+$");
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("foo").matches());
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("Foo").matches());
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("föo").matches());
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("fo-oo").matches());
```

Comment: Yes, but I’d consider the empty string valid too, so I’d use „*“ instead of „+“. The OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try StringUtils.isAlpha.

See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlpha-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer and I want to add another solution, I preferred this solution because is more personalizable.

The class Character has the method, like.isLetter(). you can see also the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

I have a code example like this:

```
public class CheckLetterInTheString {

    public static boolean isOnlyLetter(String string){
        if(string == null || string.isEmpty()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String not valid");
        }
        char[] chatString = string.toCharArray();
        for(Character character : chatString){
            if(!Character.isLetter(character) && !Character.isSpaceChar(character)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

now you can call

```
System.out.println(CheckLetterInTheString.isOnlyLetter("String only letter")); //true
System.out.println(CheckLetterInTheString.isOnlyLetter("Contains num 12")); //false
```

P.S: I like this solution because is more personalizable and I think it is more readable than a regex. But is only my opinion